# PHP 5.5 OPcache / ARM / Unable to allocate shared memory

Tags: php, apache, cross-compiling, opcache

Since PHP 5.5 OPcache is built-in.

I need to cross compile PHP with OPcache for an ARM-System. 
PHP is running as Apache Handler without any CGI/FastCGI.

The configure-Script needs to be changed, so that *flock_type = linux* is set.

After activating OPcache in php.ini by setting

```
opcache.enable=1
zend_extension=/usr/local/apache2/modules/opcache.so
opcache.memory_consumption=1
```

After starting Apache the following error appears:

> Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 8388608 bytes:
>   unknown: Numerical result out of range (34)

Whats wrong?

Best regards, Velocity